# realm.write is not saving the new items

Tags: swift, realm

Here is my code. I'm using RealmSwift and the following code to save the new items to Item class.

```
if let currentCategory = self.selectedCategory {
    do {
        try self.realm.write {
            let newItem = Item()
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            newItem.dateCreated = Date()
            currentCategory.items.append(newItem)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving new items, \(error)")
    }
}
```

I created a new instance of selectedCategory called currentCategory to append new items into my todo list. The code inside the closure is not working for some reason. I tried to test by adding a `print(newItem.title)` in the closure, that didn't print either. How to fix this issue?

Comment: If the print statement isn´t invoked your never reached that line. Probably because of `self.selectedCategory` beeing nil?

Comment: @burnsi yes that was it. Thank you i was able to fix the missing code.